# Why does function-returned data not render in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Admittedly learning react & jsx, but can't for the life of me figure out why this does not render:

```
function generateItem(item){
  return `<li><a href=${item.url}>${item.text}</a></li>`;
}

function MyList ({items}){
  return (
      <div className="list">
        <ul>
          {items.forEach(item => {
            generateItem(item);
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
  );
};
```

All it outputs (when included in my app) is an empty list:

```
<div class="list"><ul></ul></div>
```

I'm sure it's something basic and fundamental. But there I am.

https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-stallman-81ety

Comment: 1. Use map instead of forEach. 2. I would recommend to return jsx instead of a string and use the generateItem function as a *functional component* instead of a function that returns something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`items.forEach` does not return anything... the things inside curly brackets in jsx will end up transpiled to an argument in a call to React.createElement, so they need to be an expression and return a value. (check here the [transpiled version](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwEwlgbgBAxgNgQwM5IHIILYFMC8AiOMJAFzwD4AoKKYAVzkuuoG8xisMkA6AMwHsATgFEEMABYAKNhyg4yUZlSbUA5lgB2WAQnYBJdhikGAlAG4l1AL7HLS4AHp6lB-AhkgA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.4.5&externalPlugins=))

Try `items.map(item => generateItem(item))` or simply `items.map(generateItem)` instead.

here's your code edited (I also changed generateItem to return jsx instead of a string)

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sutherland-fp7kh

Comment: Hmm... so the whole "use can use regular javascript inside curly brackets" thing comes with some caveats. This helps.

Comment: @Trees4theForest your code works perfectly fine within curly brackets, it just doesn't return anything to render.

Comment: Here's an example that makes `.forEach` work by returning something from the expression. I would reject this in a code review, because `.map` is the most idiomatic way to do this, so just to illustrate the point: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-haze-4mr8q